# JavaScript if statement with condition being an HTML element of certain height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's been bothering me a little the fact that I cannot find any way to insert a if - else statement on JavaScript which refers to data about a HTML element. 
my goal is to set an "onclick" function which enlarges and image with a 200 ms delay, and another function which brings the image back to normal, always "onclick".
My code so far is:

```js
function big() {
  setTimeout(function trigger() {
    document.getElementById("p2").style.height = "300px";
    document.getElementById("p2").style.width = "300px";
  }, 200)
}

function normal(x) {
  x.style.height = "100px";
  x.style.width = "100px";
}
```

```html
<img onclick="big(this)" onclick="normal(p2)" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yck/aqg/yckaqgdcE.jpeg" id="p2" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

What i need is a code that states: if the image is 100px high onclick, enlarge it to 600px, but if clicked when it's 600px high collapse it to being 100px again.

A function that manages the clicks in a way that I can enlarge the image if small, and make it small if big with only a click.

The transition is possible due to the delay I coded, but I can't seem to find any expression to clarify the height factor.
Is it possible?

Comment: You can’t have two `onclick` attributes on the same element.

Comment: do you want to toggle?

Comment: Why don't you create a javascript function with your if/else logic, and have your `onclick` call the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try following code in javascript

```
function toggle(x) {
  if (x.style.height == "100px") {
    x.style.height = "300px";
    x.style.width = "300px";
  } else {
    x.style.height = "100px";
    x.style.width = "100px";
  }
}
```

and this in html

```
<img onclick="toggle(this)" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yck/aqg/yckaqgdcE.jpeg" id="p2" height="100px" width="100px"/>
```

Comment: thank you for your help! the code is perfect for the purpose now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is indeed possible. Just use a single function with your logic inside that's called with a click like this:

```js
function myFunction(img) {
  img.style.transition = "all .2s";
  if (img.height == "100") {
    img.style.height = "600px";
    img.style.width = "600px";
  } else{
    img.style.height = "100px";
    img.style.width = "100px";
  }
}
```

```html
<img onclick="myFunction(this)" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yck/aqg/yckaqgdcE.jpeg" id="p2" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach the `onclick` event twice on the same element with `onclick` attribute.

And instead of using two functions to resize the image, you can use only one function where you test over the image `width` and `height` then resize it accordingly.

This is how should be your function defined:

```
function resize(image) {
  if (image.style.width === "100px" && image.style.height === "100px")
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("p2").style.height = "300px";
      document.getElementById("p2").style.width = "300px";
    }, 200)
  else {
    image.style.height = "100px";
    image.style.width = "100px";
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function resize(image) {
  if (image.style.width === "100px" && image.style.height === "100px")
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("p2").style.height = "300px";
      document.getElementById("p2").style.width = "300px";
    }, 200)
  else {
    image.style.height = "100px";
    image.style.width = "100px";
  }
}
```

```html
<img onclick="resize(this)" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yck/aqg/yckaqgdcE.jpeg" id="p2" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

**Note:**

There's no need to give a name to the callback function of `setTimeout`, you can get rid of `trigger`.

Comment: thank you so much the code works perfectly, and excuse my clumsiness :)

Comment: @DarySparta you are welcome, glad it helps. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery for this.

```
$(function (){
  $(".imgSizeToggle").on('click',function (){
    if($(this).width() < 300){$(this).stop().animate({height:'300px',width:'300px'});}
    else{$(this).stop().animate({height:'100px',width:'100px'}); }

  });
})
```

and use the css class on your image element

```
<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yck/aqg/yckaqgdcE.jpeg" class="imgSizeToggle" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/UPvYJiieeBcnQbUORBUx?p=preview